# Using Conda Environment from PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, conda

I've looked at all the responses in the search and specifically [Use Conda environment in pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42746732/use-conda-environment-in-pycharm) without resolving my problem.

I'm on Win10 using the latest Anaconda and PyCharm for Python 3.6.  The situation is that I've created a new environment using Conda which uses the Python version available in the base environment.  Therefore, there is no python.exe in the newly created environment.  In PyCharm, when I try to select the Conda environment, the dialog apparently does not see a Python there and refuses to set that as the environment.

In PyCharm, I create a new Project (pure Python) and set the location for the project in my PyCharmProjects directory.  I then try to select existing interpreter and navigate to the appropriate Conda environment which I'm unable to select.

I'm not sure if there is something I don't understand or there is actually a problem here, but I'm getting a bit frustrated trying 
to find the proper approach.  Any help appreciated.
   --Don

Comment: how you create the environment ? how you connecting the environment ? are you able to start the python into the new activated environment ?

Comment: A quick hack: try using a symbolic link in the condo env folder

Comment: I create the environment using Conda.  I'm *trying* to connect to the environment from PyCharm.  Python is fine if I don't use PyCharm - I can't set it up using PyCharm.

Comment: Thanks for the symlink idea.  Not quite sure how to do it, but I can figure that out.  Thx,

Answer (score 1):

When you create the conda environment from cmd prompt do you explicitly tell it what python you want to use?

```
conda create --environmentName python=3.6
```

That should place a `python.exe` in your environment.