# How to add different python environment to pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, python-venv

I have two versions of python (2.7 and 3.6) in my system. I have created a virtual environment for python 3.6 using conda commands. Now I have python36 venv in my system. I wanted to use this python version in my Pycharm or Jupyter notebook.

Please advice on how it can be done?

Comment: I think this is not a duplicate one. I wanted to add that virtual environment into pycharm. But when I click + , it is not showing the environment I have created

Comment: See this one: [Use Conda environment in pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42746732/use-conda-environment-in-pycharm)

Answer (score 0):

Go to:

Pycharm -> Preferences -> Search for project interpreter in Project -> Select the path of python in virtual_env created, or create a new one(by clicking on gear).