# Using a 32-bit conda environment in PyCharm 2019

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, x86, pycharm, conda

I created a 32-bit conda environment from my 64-bit root environment with the following commands:

```
set CONDA_FORCE_32BIT=1
conda create -n py37_32 python=3.7
```

I then activated the environment and installed numpy and pandas:

```
conda activate py37_32
conda install numpy pandas
```

I can see that the 32-bit versions of all the packages required are being used. After activating this environment I can run my application without any problems from the command line.

The problem arises when I try to use this environment in PyCharm. In the run configuration for my application I specified the python interpreter as a system interpreter with a path to python.exe of the environment as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42747689/2593236), but when I run this configuration I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/patri/OneDrive - The University of Western Ontario/Combining Sectors Vensim/Scenarios/run_scenarios.py", line 1, in <module>
    import venpy as vp
  File "C:\Users\patri\Anaconda3\envs\py37_32\lib\site-packages\venpy\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .venpy import load
  File "C:\Users\patri\Anaconda3\envs\py37_32\lib\site-packages\venpy\venpy.py", line 14, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\patri\Anaconda3\envs\py37_32\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\Users\patri\Anaconda3\envs\py37_32\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . import _mklinit
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I don't know why this would be different from the command line other than maybe I'm not setting the interpreter for this configuration properly.

I can't create the environment in PyCharm directly as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46133678/2593236) because I need to specify 32-bit not just the python version.

Any thoughts on how to run a 32-bit conda environment in PyCharm? What could be the problem here?