# How to install osmnx in Pycharm

Tags: python, gdal, osmnx, r-tree, fiona

I am trying to install OSMNX module in Pycharm (using Python 3.7.2).
I tried installing it using pip install osmnx but got the following error[![error][1]][1]
i have also tried using .whl files from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#fiona][2] but I cannot identify how/what steps to follow. Please provide some clear steps!

Most of the other question are answered w.r.t. conda environment. I have to use Pcharm only.

Input in any form is highly appreciated!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdJDN.png
[2]: [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#fiona](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#fiona)

Comment: The order you install the gis libraries matters.  I use the order gdal, friona, shapely.

Comment: @dubbbdan Please provide steps to install gdal , fiona in Pycharm because Pycharm gives error when I install normally?

Comment: I am using gdal version `2040100`, fiona version `1.8.6` and shapely version `1.7.0`

Comment: Versions of Gdal available in Pcharm are 3. something. What is this 2040100? 
And more specifically how do you install gdal and fiona when Pycahrm gives error ?

Comment: I dont use pycharm.  There might be another combination of verstions that work on py 3.7, but thats what i would look for.

Comment: The wheel i have is named `GDAL-2.4.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`.  I don't see it available on Chris Gohlke's site anymore.  I am not sure who else serves those data.

Comment: Oh thanks but I want answers wrt Pycharm only. If there is any way to resolve this issue in Pycharm kindly let me know

Comment: Your issue has nothing to do with PyCharm.  It has everything to do with how the GIS libraries link together in your environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

> I have to use Pcharm only.

Does that mean you *cannot* use conda + pycharm on your system for some reason? If you *can*, then:

1. [Install OSMnx with conda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62958055/7321942)
2. [Use Conda environment in pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42746732/use-conda-environment-in-pycharm)

This is by far the easiest (and recommended) solution.
If you *cannot*, then you must manually install the dependencies. This is a nontrivial process, especially if you're on Windows. OSMnx itself is pure Python and its installation is simple, but its dependencies have C extensions that require compilation.

You can see OSMnx's dependencies [here](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/blob/master/requirements.txt) and you'll have to install them one at a time. All of the tricky dependencies are brought in via geopandas, and you can read more about its installation details and dependencies [here](https://geopandas.org/install.html#dependencies).